# Error while installing "bincopy" -- pip install bincopy

Tags: pip

C:\W2\build_files\project_specific\python_scripts>pip install bincopy

DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.

Collecting bincopy
Using cached bincopy-17.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)

Collecting humanfriendly
Using cached humanfriendly-10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (86 kB)

Collecting argparse-addons>=0.4.0
Using cached argparse_addons-0.6.0.tar.gz (3.5 kB)

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\python27\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\\users\\hjvnk4\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-pqjrju\\argparse-addons\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'c:\\users\\hjvnk4\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-pqjrju\\argparse-addons\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'c:\users\hjvnk4\appdata\local\temp\pip-pip-egg-info-i3avsj'
     cwd: c:\users\hjvnk4\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-pqjrju\argparse-addons\

Complete output (8 lines):

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "c:\users\hjvnk4\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-pqjrju\argparse-addons\setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    import argparse_addons

  File "argparse_addons.py", line 19
    f'{string} is not in the range {self.minimum}..{self.maximum}')
                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

C:\W2\build_files\project_specific\python_scripts>

Comment: You're missing a bracket: ```f'({string} is not in the range {self.minimum}..{self.maximum}')```, note the missing ```(```, has nothing to do with the install. Also I could be wrong but I don't think python2.7 accepts fancy strings? I could be wrong though.

Comment: Looks like you're running Python 2.7 - f-string support wasn't introduced until Python 3.6. Have you considered upgrading, considering Python 2 was EOL in January 2020?

Answer (score 0):

The answer here is clear: you are using an unsupported Python (2.7). Newer versions of Python included new syntax, so you will find this kind of messages. There are 2 options to work around this:

1. Don't use the latest versions of packages and extensions. This is not a great idea, though. Do it if you *really* need Python 2.
2. Update your Python version. Consider Python 3.7 or greater.

Comment: Actually I have to use Python 2 only. It is project need.
While building it generate error that BinCopy module is not found
While installing BinCopy it generates above mentioned error

Comment: You should install an old `bincopy`, that supports Python 2. The latest compatible version that I found is 17.8.0. To install this specific version, run `pip install bincopy==17.8.0`. If you are still getting errors, you can look for older versions [here](https://pypi.org/project/bincopy/#history), and install via `pip install bincopy==[your desired version]`.

Answer (score 0):

## Remove python2

```
sudo apt purge -y python2.7-minimal
```